# mysql group and order rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have following table 'persons' with same persons in different rows

```
id |   firstname   |   surname   | date_created
------------------------------------------------------
3  | Nelli         | Schaller    | 2017-08-22 20:57:19
------------------------------------------------------
4  | Carl          | Schaller    | 2019-06-21 08:29:45
------------------------------------------------------
48 | Nelli         | Schaller    | 2020-06-25 13:06:09
------------------------------------------------------   
49 | Carl          | Schaller    | 2020-06-25 13:06:09
```

What I want to get are all unique Schallers with the biggest id / newest date_created value.

I tried this

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(surname, ", ", firstname) AS person, date_created
FROM persons
WHERE
surname LIKE "schall%"
GROUP by firstname, surname 
ORDER BY date_createdDESC, surname ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

but get only as expected the first two entries (id 3 and 4) but I need 48 and 49.
As mentioned in some comment in this case the LIKE statement isn't necessary but in real live it will be the source for an autocomplete field so I need the LIKE
Any idea how to manage that?

Comment: did you forget to include the group by in your example? the query you wrote would return 4 rows not 2.

Comment: You are right..edit

Comment: I would be careful with GROUP BY in mysql. Many other RDBMS would error on that query because the columns in the select that are not in the group by statement need to have aggregate functions (MIN,MAX,etc) for the query to be valid. MySQL instead will return ANY_VALUE if an aggregate is not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.id, CONCAT(p.surname, ', ', p.firstname) AS person, p.date_created
FROM persons p
WHERE p.surname LIKE '%schall%'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM persons WHERE firstname = p.firstname AND surname = p.surname AND id > p.id)
ORDER BY p.date_created DESC, person
```

If the condition to pick the latest of each group is the column `date_created` then change:

```
...AND id > p.id
```

with

```
...AND date_created > p.date_created
```

Comment: The complete name was only for clearance, in real life it will be the source for an autocomplete field and so I need the LIKE to get all starting with something particular

Comment: Then you must rephrase the requirement in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery  with group for max id

```
select t.max_id, t.person, m.date_created
from (
    SELECT max(id) max_id, CONCAT(surname, ", ", firstname) AS person
    FROM persons
    WHERE surname LIKE "schall%"
    ORDER BY date_createdDESC, surname ASC 
    GROUP BY CONCAT(surname, ", ", firstname)

    ) t 
    inner join  persons m ON  CONCAT(m.surname, ", ", m.firstname) = t.person
        and m-id = t.max_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM persons p
LEFT JOIN persons p2 ON p2.firstname = p.firstname 
    AND p2.lastname = p.lastname
    AND p2.date_created > p.date_created
WHERE p2.id IS NULL
```

This is SQL Server syntax but MySQL is probably similar.

I'm assuming your `id` field doesn't need to be checked as well as the `date_created` since it's an identity column and would be larger anyway for the latter created records, but obviously adjust to your actual data.

Comment: Oh, they are not duplicates. I must admit that I left out some other columns for clarity. They contain additional data and I have to keep all these Schallers. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Ole_S Then just use the SELECT part

Comment: Then it has to be: p2.date_created < p.date_created

Comment: @Ole_S update should work. If you have multiple rows for the same person your data isn't normalized properly.